# What is the purpose of AutoReceiveMessage Envelope(SelectChildName(actorname(some payload))?

Tags: akka

It seems like AutoReceiveMessage is sent when the Actor gets the Kill or PoisonKill or AddressTerminated message. But in some cases, the following type of AutoReceiveMessage is sent:

```
received AutoReceiveMessage Envelope(SelectChildName(123_321,{some payload}),Actor[some actor])
```

- What does this message mean?
- Can these types of messages be subscribed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These messages (including `SelectChildPattern` and `SelectParent`) are used in the implementation of sending messages to an `ActorSelection`. You cannot see them inside your behavior because their behavior is hard-coded by Akka.